# win10toast python change program title in notification center

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, toast

I am using the [win10toastpersist](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast-persist/) module, and I am wondering how I can change the "Python" title in the notification center to a custom value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `show_toast` method? If, then there you can pass the title parameter.

Also, if possible show us your code.

Comment: This is more of a comment and a clarification question. Please use your commenting privilege. (Also, elsewhere, I seem to have scared you away from making an answer. Sorry. I really only wanted to provide you some background info, so that you can make an informed decision on whether and how to answer there. If you decide to answer, it is nothing I should prevent. The question was deleted however.....) Have fun.

Comment: The concept of "conditional answer" exists. It would be something like "If your problem is caused by ... then the solution is to .... because ..... That way you could create a clear assertive answer here.

Comment: I am using the show_toast method.  What is the title parameter?`toast.show_toast(notificationTitle,f"{fileName} has been moved to the {folderName} folder.",duration=notificationDuration,icon_path=iconPath,threaded=True)`